# Unable to cast object of type 'Microsoft.Xrm.Sdk.Money' to type 'System.IConvertible'.Detail:

Tags: c#, plugins, dynamics-crm, microsoft-dynamics, dynamics-365

I'm getting this error when I try converting from Money data to decimal in my CRM plugin project. Please how can I solve this error.

Here is my code below -
Sample Code

[image: 1].

This is a sample of the error output -
Sample Error Message

[image: 2]

Comment: First of all, don't post images of code, post the actual code. Secondly, you can't just convert anything into a decimal. Thirdly, `Microsoft.Xrm.Sdk.Money` has a property you can use to get the decimal amount: `membershipType.senior_applocationFee.Value`

Comment: Thank you, this worked for me and I'll post the actual code next time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't just convert anything into a decimal.

However, the [`Microsoft.Xrm.Sdk.Money`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.xrm.sdk.money?view=dataverse-sdk-latest) class has a [`Value`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.xrm.sdk.money.value?view=dataverse-sdk-latest#microsoft-xrm-sdk-money-value) property you can use to get the decimal amount:

```
var membershipFee = membershipType.senior_applocationFee.Value;
```

Comment: make sure you check Money is not null before getting the Value property